# How can I learn how multimedia file formats work?

Tags: video, audio, media, codec

I have always been a bit puzzled about how audio/video file formats work, and how the extension of a media file (e.g. mp4) doesn't always tell the whole story about what media formats the file contains and how it is encoded. I am starting to learn about the existence of container formats and codecs, and would like to learn this hands-on by looking at some actual media files.

A while back a friend showed me a program that can inspect a media file and draw a diagram of what is contained in the file. I remember these diagrams looked a bit like flowcharts. Does this ring a bell for anyone?

I am also interested if anyone has other recommendations for other good ways to learn how multimedia file formats work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Get the [GSpot tool](http://www.headbands.com/gspot/) for windows to start with.
- Then, read up the Wikipedia [Container format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format_%28digital%29) page and its links
- Gizmodo article: [Giz Explains: Every Video Format You Need to Know](http://gizmodo.com/5093670/giz-explains-every-video-format-you-need-to-know)
- [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/) will play almost any format you throw at it

  - it has a [good Wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Fileformat) to search through too
- [another reference](http://www.shallowsky.com/linux/videoformats.html)

Answer (score 4):

The program you mean is [GraphEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphedit)/[GraphStudio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GraphStudio).

Wikipedia is good for learning about this sort of thing:

- [Comparison of video codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_codecs)
- [Container formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format_%28digital%29)

Generally, multimedia files are composed of encoded video stored inside a container format.

But after that, when it comes to *playing* the file, the question becomes all tangled up with how the OS actually turns that into an image on screen. Then you are looking at [multimedia frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimedia_framework), which is where your filter graph diagram comes in.

Comment: Note that rendering filters are part of the directshow framework; software may choose to render without using a multimedia framework, but it is generally better/easier to use the framework. Also directshow is outdated nowadays in favor of WMF.